# Postgres: Using a value in the same row to fill in a colum

Tags: postgresql

Trying to fill in a reference to an original 'shared' post via a query on the same row. Seems like the other select statements are working fine and dandy but the self-reflected on is not.

The query looks like so

```
SELECT 
    posts.*,
    (
        SELECT to_jsonb(users)
        FROM myapp.users 
        WHERE users.id = posts."userId"
    ) as user,
    // !! Breaking here ///
    (
        SELECT to_jsonb(posts)
        FROM myapp.posts 
        WHERE posts.id = posts."originalPostId"
    ) as "originalSharedPost"
FROM myapp.posts
```

As you can see, the user is filled in but the original shared post is not.
[image]

```
Data
[
    {
        "id": "z1aN2n1tnqJAhW3-",
        "markdown": "test",
        "trendingScore": 10,
        "likes": 0,
        "dislikes": 0,
        "shares": 0,
        "views": 10,
        "originalPostId": null,
        "recipeId": null,
        "wasEdited": 0,
        "medais": [
        ],
        "hashTags": "{}",
        "ipAddressOfPost": "176.111.206.130",
        "location": {
            "city": "Oslo",
            "country": "NO",
            "isRough": true,
            "latLong": [
                59.8468,
                10.7747
            ],
            "longName": "NO",
            "timezone": "Europe/Oslo",
            "shortName": "Oslo"
        },
        "i18nLanguagesDetected": "{en}",
        "createdAt": "2022-10-27 09:56:23.733+02",
        "updatedAt": "2022-10-27 10:36:21.428+02",
        "userId": "ckEQtm",
        "reports": 0,
        "recipe": null,
        "user": {
            "id": "ckEQtm",
            "bio": "",
            "name": "Olly",
            "isBanned": false,
            "location": {
                "city": "Oslo",
                "country": "NO",
                "isRough": true,
                "latLong": [
                    59.8468,
                    10.7747
                ],
                "longName": "NO",
                "timezone": "Europe/Oslo",
                "shortName": "Oslo"
            },
            "createdAt": "2022-10-25T12:27:18.364+02:00",
            "isDeleted": false,
            "isFlagged": false,
            "isVisable": true,
            "updatedAt": "2022-10-27T10:56:41.802+02:00",
            "profileUrl": {
                "id": "L9RtfueTEWU",
                "url": "https://storage.googleapis.com/myapp-dev/uploads/ckEQtm/images/QufsJIMvt_f9axN3E",
                "name": "me-nice-bg.jpg",
                "mimeType": "image/jpeg",
                "originalUrl": "https://storage.googleapis.com/myapp-dev/uploads/ckEQtm/images/QufsJIMvt_f9axN3E_original"
            },
            "phoneNumber": "+1234455",
            "recipeViews": 0,
            "profileViews": 0,
            "followerCount": 1,
            "trendingScore": 1,
            "followingCount": 1,
            "ipAddressOfUser": "176.111.206.130",
            "isPlatformAdmin": false,
            "isCompanyEnabled": false,
            "lastOpenedAppIso": "2022-10-27T10:56:41.801+02:00",
            "recipeTrendingScore": 1
        },
        "originalSharedPost": null
    },
    {
        "id": "nI0aVB92PT1oRKDy",
        "markdown": "Check this recipe out",
        "trendingScore": 11,
        "likes": 0,
        "dislikes": 0,
        "shares": 0,
        "views": 11,
        "originalPostId": "z1aN2n1tnqJAhW3-",
        "recipeId": "LyvIGDaDK",
        "wasEdited": 0,
        "medais": [
            {
                "id": "32_fxP3_G9n",
                "url": "https://storage.googleapis.com/myapp-dev/dummy_profile_photos/profile_default_1.jpg",
                "name": "test",
                "mimeType": "image/jpeg",
                "originalUrl": null
            }
        ],
        "hashTags": "{}",
        "ipAddressOfPost": "84.211.160.110",
        "location": {
            "city": "Fredrikstad",
            "country": "NO",
            "isRough": true,
            "latLong": [
                59.2198,
                10.9247
            ],
            "longName": "NO",
            "timezone": "Europe/Oslo",
            "shortName": "Fredrikstad"
        },
        "i18nLanguagesDetected": "{en}",
        "createdAt": "2022-10-27 09:56:31.96+02",
        "updatedAt": "2022-10-27 10:36:23.713+02",
        "userId": "ckEQtm",
        "reports": 0,
        "recipe": {
            "id": "LyvIGDaDK",
            "name": "Avocado Toast",
            "views": 1,
            "medias": [
                {
                    "id": "32_fxP3_G9n",
                    "url": "https://storage.googleapis.com/myapp-dev/dummy_profile_photos/profile_default_1.jpg",
                    "name": "test",
                    "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
                }
            ],
            "userId": "ckEQtm",
            "location": {
                "city": "Fredrikstad",
                "country": "NO",
                "isRough": true,
                "latLong": [
                    59.2198,
                    10.9247
                ],
                "longName": "NO",
                "timezone": "Europe/Oslo",
                "shortName": "Fredrikstad"
            },
            "createdAt": "2022-10-25T12:27:58.761+02:00",
            "updatedAt": "2022-10-25T12:27:58.761+02:00",
            "categories": [
                "midnight-snack"
            ],
            "description": "The best meal",
            "ingredients": [
                {
                    "ingredientId": "By_2yVOjr",
                    "amountAndInfo": "1 Avocado",
                    "weightInGrams": 215,
                    "ingredientName": "Avocado"
                },
                {
                    "ingredientId": "JL7hQeZfy",
                    "amountAndInfo": "1 Slice",
                    "weightInGrams": 30,
                    "ingredientName": "1 Slice - Toasted Multigrain Bread"
                },
                {
                    "ingredientId": "w0SywAGZR",
                    "amountAndInfo": "Spicy for the USA",
                    "weightInGrams": 0.05,
                    "ingredientName": "Chilli flakes"
                }
            ],
            "cookingSteps": [
                {
                    "id": "xKknDJktuuo",
                    "media": {
                        "id": "ggPZMXVDHjb",
                        "url": "https://storage.googleapis.com/myapp-dev/dummy_profile_photos/profile_default_1.jpg",
                        "name": "test",
                        "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
                    },
                    "explination": "Non est tempora consequatur est et quia omnis.\nNumquam et voluptatem aliquam porro."
                },
                {
                    "id": "fWSH0QHhFo-",
                    "media": {
                        "id": "C1uFNzmBx23",
                        "url": "https://storage.googleapis.com/myapp-dev/dummy_profile_photos/profile_default_1.jpg",
                        "name": "test",
                        "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
                    },
                    "explination": "Et delectus sint illum culpa.\nVoluptate iure magnam maiores inventore quo eum amet sapiente.\nPossimus vitae possimus amet similique."
                },
                {
                    "id": "j6wG8I2_cok",
                    "media": {
                        "id": "tFJ2XEqXaji",
                        "url": "https://storage.googleapis.com/myapp-dev/dummy_profile_photos/profile_default_1.jpg",
                        "name": "test",
                        "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
                    },
                    "explination": "Earum facere quo minus maiores quis nobis et quo.\nVeniam facilis soluta alias fugiat et nobis asperiores in.\nEt et qui hic laborum eligendi temporibus et."
                }
            ],
            "trendingScore": 1,
            "ipAddressOfUser": "84.211.160.110",
            "recipeLangaugeKey": "en",
            "totalTimeToCookMs": 900000
        },
        "user": {
            "id": "ckEQtm",
            "bio": "",
            "name": "Olly",
            "isBanned": false,
            "location": {
                "city": "Oslo",
                "country": "NO",
                "isRough": true,
                "latLong": [
                    59.8468,
                    10.7747
                ],
                "longName": "NO",
                "timezone": "Europe/Oslo",
                "shortName": "Oslo"
            },
            "createdAt": "2022-10-25T12:27:18.364+02:00",
            "isDeleted": false,
            "isFlagged": false,
            "isVisable": true,
            "updatedAt": "2022-10-27T10:56:41.802+02:00",
            "profileUrl": {
                "id": "L9RtfueTEWU",
                "url": "https://storage.googleapis.com/myapp-dev/uploads/ckEQtm/images/QufsJIMvt_f9axN3E",
                "name": "me-nice-bg.jpg",
                "mimeType": "image/jpeg",
                "originalUrl": "https://storage.googleapis.com/myapp-dev/uploads/ckEQtm/images/QufsJIMvt_f9axN3E_original"
            },
            "phoneNumber": "+1234455",
            "recipeViews": 0,
            "profileViews": 0,
            "followerCount": 1,
            "trendingScore": 1,
            "followingCount": 1,
            "ipAddressOfUser": "176.111.206.130",
            "isPlatformAdmin": false,
            "isCompanyEnabled": false,
            "lastOpenedAppIso": "2022-10-27T10:56:41.801+02:00",
            "recipeTrendingScore": 1
        },
        "originalSharedPost": null
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out.

Had to use WITH RECURSIVE (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

```
WITH RECURSIVE rpost AS (SELECT 
    posts.*,
    (
        SELECT to_jsonb(recipes)
        FROM myapp.recipes 
        WHERE recipes.id = posts."recipeId"
    ) as recipe,
    (
        SELECT to_jsonb(users)
        FROM myapp.users 
        WHERE users.id = posts."userId"
    ) as user
FROM myapp.posts)
# SECOND QUERY REFERENCES WITH
SELECT *,
    (
        SELECT to_jsonb(posts)
        FROM myapp.posts 
        WHERE posts.id = rpost."originalPostId"
    ) as "originalSharedPost"
FROM rpost
```

--

If you want the same datatype as the original data you can use json builder in the second query like so:

```
SELECT *,
    (
    
        SELECT json_build_object(
        'post',to_jsonb(posts), 
        'userLight',
            (
                SELECT to_jsonb(users)
                FROM myapp.users 
                WHERE users.id = posts."userId"
            ),
        'recipe',
            (
                SELECT to_jsonb(recipes)
                FROM myapp.recipes 
                WHERE recipes.id = posts."recipeId"
            )
        )
        FROM myapp.posts 
        WHERE posts.id = rpost."originalPostId"
        
    ) as "originalSharedPost"
FROM rpost
```

Comment: I don't get this.  Why post a question with no information about tables for example, and then answer it yourself with different tables?  And how is this a Recursive query (without UNION ALL)?  Is this some trick to get points (asking seriously)?

Comment: @BjarniRagnarsson I gave an example of the data in the original question? I'm not interested in points. I don't tend to use Union or Joins I find them annoying.

Comment: @BjarniRagnarsson I do have a problem though. The original post needs to have the user and recipe data filled in, cannot figure that out.

Comment: Ok. I suggest posting the definition (and data) for vegiano.posts, vegiano.users, vegiano.recipes - the relevant columns at least - instead of a large json object to figure them out.  RECURSIVE queries require UNION ALL by definition (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE).  I'm not trying to bring it to the table and I'm surprised this compiles actually.

Comment: @BjarniRagnarsson why do recursive quires require union? I figured it out using Json builder, will update my answer.

Comment: @BjarniRagnarsson I had to use recursive to fill in the JSON for the referenced object, it's for 'sharing' posts on posts. I'm trying to avoid using JOINS or UNION because they are not nice to work with on the backend. Returning json blobs is a lot better (we're using typescript)